# IntelliJ IDEA add final to auto-generated setters

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to add the final keyword to the parameters in my auto-generated setters in IntelliJ IDEA 14. I know that I can create a copy of the current template which is used for setter methods:

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
  static ##
#end
void set$StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project)))($field.type $paramName) {
  #if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
      this.##
    #else
      $classname.##
    #end
  #end
  $field.name = $paramName;
}
```

But even after playing around with it for hours, I can't work out how to add "final" to it and get it to work in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't need to do this with templates.

Go to Settings (Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) / Preferences (Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)

- `Editor | Code Style | Java`
- Select the Code Generation tab
- Tick `Make generated parameters final`

Comment: @Gilson I just tried it with IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 and it worked as expected. What was the problem?

Comment: I am also using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 and if I press alt+insert and choose setters, the parameter will not be final. My teammates have same issue as well.